# html navigation menu how to highlight the selected menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is my menu when I click on HOME I need it to be active with background color changed.
 can I achieve this only with css or I have other options too?

html code:

```
<div id="menu"><br></div>
<div style="position: absolute;margin-top: -40px;">
<ul>

<li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="#">SETTINGS</a></li>

</ul>
</div>
```

css:

```
#menu {
       width:100%;
       height:40px;
       background-color: #AC58FA;
       opacity:0.5; 
       margin-top:75px; 
         }
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    oveflow:hidden;
    }

li {
    float:left;
   }

a:link, a:visited{
                  display:block;
                  width:204px;
                  font-weight: bold;
                  color: #FFFFFF;
                  background-color: transparent;
                  text-align: center;
                  padding: 10px;
                  text-decoration: none;
                   }


a:hover, a:active {
                    background-color: black;
                  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nitinkolmi/xraobuxq/

Comment: You can do it with jQuery `addClass()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding active class using jQuery, [Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/stanze/xraobuxq/2/)

```
var selectLi = $('ul li a');
$(selectLi).click(function() {
   $('li a').removeClass('active');    
   $(this).addClass('active');    
})
```

Answer (score 0):

No basically only with CSS it is not possible as you need to bound an event, so based on that you have to dynamically change css of active menu option.

For this you need to use JS/Jquery to bound your event and process the event..

Answer (score 0):

Like what you did on hower, you need to add classname to the clicked menu item with the help on onclick event and add related style in css.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class: `.menuHover{background-color:black;}`

And use the jQuery function to bind your menu:

```
$("ul li a").hover(
    function(){
        $(this).addClass('menuHover');
    },
    function(){
        $(this).removeClass('menuHover');
    }
);
```